# How to solve this equation $ \sqrt{\log_{10}(-x)} = \log_{10}\sqrt{x^2} $

Tags: logarithms

I am new to logarithms, I have the following equation

$ \ \sqrt{\log_{10}(-x)} = \log_{10}\sqrt{x^2} \ $

I tried by squaring both sides, which yielded me

$ \ \log_{10}(-x) = ( \log_{10}\vert x \vert )^2 \ $

So,

$ \ \log_{10}(-x) = ( \log_{10}\vert x \vert )^2 \ $

Or
$ \ \log_{10}(-x) = ( \log_{10}\vert x \vert ) ( \log_{10}\vert x \vert )  \ $

Or
$ \ \log_{10}(-x) = ( \log_{10}2\vert x \vert ) \ $

Which on further solving, doesn't gives me the solutions.
What is the correct way?

Comment: What should I do then? I'm not cheating at homework

Comment: @Typhon, that's a bit harsh, don't you think? I've seen many posts with far less work and/or thought slide. He has even shown some work and thoughts. Not every post on M.SE needs to be "useful to us"

Comment: @Typhon But he has shown his work in this instance, yes?

Comment: @Typhon The previous questions were different from this. I was stuck at this so I asked with all my attempts. But even then you down voted? :(

Comment: @RaviPrakash do not worry about downvotes or rep; as long as your questions are answered, that is all that matters. More than that, do not worry about asking a lot of questions about a similar topic. Just do your best and show your efforts (as you have done so).

Comment: @ThomasGrubb I will always remember your guidelines. :)

Comment: @Typhon Thanks for your kindness :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you mixed up your log rules. Here's one way to go about it: you know $log_{10}$ of a negative number is undefined, so $x$ must be negative for $\log_{10}(-x)$ to make sense. Further, you know $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$; thus the question turns into solving (by setting $y=-x$)
$$
\sqrt{\log_{10}(y)}=\log_{10}(y)
$$
Now when do we have that the square root of a number must be equal to that number? We get $\log_{10}(y)=0$ or $\log_{10}(y)=1$. Can you go from here?

Comment: Looks like a case of telepathy. Maybe I should have checked your answer while I was finishing mine off.

Comment: @Typhon The OP says they are "new to logarithms;" thus I am assuming that they have not heard of branch cuts and complex logs.

Comment: @Lubin hopefully this is a case of great minds thinking alike and not fools never differing :)

Comment: @Typhon, logarithms are definable for negative numbers, but they are not defined. That is, deciding what $\log(-1)$ shall be requires a choice, on which honest people of good will may easily disagree.

Comment: @Typhon I would be very interested in seeing an "introductory" calc course which covers integration, let alone complex integration. In the United States at least it is common for calc 1 courses to cover limits, series, and differentiability, and not much more. Regardless, keep in mind what you said: if that is the case, it is certainly not the norm, and you should probably not assume knowledge of complex functions when talking to people who are just beginning logarithms

Answer (score 2):

First of all, $\log a \log b \neq \log ab$ in general.

$$\log (-x) = (\log |x|)^2$$

From LHS, $-x > 0 \implies x < 0$.

$$\log(-x) = (\log(-x))^2 \implies \log(-x) = 0 \text{ or } 1 \implies x = -1 \text{ or }-10$$

**Edit**: If the domain of $x$ is not restricted to real numbers then let $x = r e^{i\theta} \implies -x = re^{i(\theta+\pi)}$,

$$\log(re^{i(\theta+\pi)}) = (\log r)^2 \implies \log r + i(\theta+\pi) = (\log r)^2$$

$$\implies \theta = -\pi \wedge \log r = (\log r)^2 \implies \theta = -\pi \wedge r = 1 \text{ or } 10$$

Comment: Domain of $\log x$ is $x > 0$.

Comment: I think the OP needs a solution for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Typhon Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, you must remember that $\sqrt{x^2\,}=|x|$. Second, you must remember that logarithms are defined only for positive inputs, so on the left hand side, we need $x$ to be negative, which means that $|x|=-x$. As a result, your equation to solve becomes $\sqrt{\log_{10}(-x)}=\log_{10}(-x)$. Calling $z=\log_{10}(-x)$, the equation becomes $\sqrt z=z$, which happens only for $z=0,1$, as you can easily check. Thus, in case $z=0$, you have $-x=1$ and $x=-1$, while in case $z=1$, you have $-x=10$ and $x=-10$.